# Getting Visual Studio style home key behaviour in PhpStorm

Tags: ide, phpstorm

Where hitting the home key moves the caret to the end of the indentation if it's not there already or to the first column of the line if it's already there. Same behaviour as `0` and `^` in Vim.

The default behaviour is not very usefull. Don't think I've ever wanted to move to the first column in a line

Comment: `Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Smart Keys --> Home` ??

Comment: You are correct. Ideavim seems to interfere with the setting. Are you an ideavim user?

Comment: Nope. If you think that it's an issue of ideavim plugin then you may submit new ticket to appropriate Issue Tracker -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/VIM